# I Want To Make a Python Program To Install a library using Os & Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pip, operating-system

I'm Trying To Make a Program that first opens a cmd with a specific direction and then type the Command pip install tqdm for example
I Have a program that runs multiple libraries and Want To Make sure that the user has installed them then after that the program get Opened
here is my code below hope I Get Some Help And Wrote the Necessary details

```
import os
import tkinter as tk

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 350, bg = 'lightsteelblue2', relief = 'raised')
canvas1.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Install Packages', bg = 'lightsteelblue2')
label1.config(font=('helvetica', 20))
canvas1.create_window(150, 80, window=label1)

def installPackages ():
    os.system('start cmd /k cd C:\\Users\\Pc\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Scripts pip install tqdm') 
    
button1 = tk.Button(text='      Install Packages     ', command=installPackages, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(150, 180, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

My Question is how to make the cmd start with a specific directory + specific command using os
Thank You Again

Comment: You forgot to tell what is wrong.

Comment: Keep in mind, if you are making an exe with this, you don't need to separately install these libraries in the client system.

Comment: What is your question? Note that if you have working code and are looking for general improvements, this would be more appropriate for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) – be sure to check their [question guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions) first, though.

Comment: @TheLizzard Is it necessary to have `canvas` as master rather than `root` for an item to be placed in the canvas? I don't think so

Comment: Sorry I've Writted But Only in my Notpad My Question is like that  how to make the cmd start with a specific directory + specific command using os Thank You Again

Comment: ``os.system`` is a low-level interface.  Why not use ``subprocess``? It should provide what you want out of the box.

Comment: Thank You All For Your Answers it worked